# How to create shell script command so that it will self-detruct after performing it's task?

Tags: shell-script

I want to make command run in Ubuntu 13.10 as soon as I login. I know for that I have to add certain command in `~/.profile` file. That's not the problem.

I want to certain line of that `~/.profile` file to be deleted and to be restored in it's original state. I want to perform that task just one time, so any help regarding that issue would be appreciated.

#### EDIT #1

I'm attempting to run `sudo startx` as soon as I login. I've found that using that command gives me a GUI temporarily. But, to open some file with a GUI, I need to use `gnome-open <file path>`.

Comment: Can you explain what you want more? Just the line deleted or all the lines leading up to this one?

Comment: Hmm. This smells like script kiddie to me. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Please demonstrate basic understanding of shell commands or file manipulation so we know what further research to recommend.

Comment: @slm I just want to delete just the line. I want to delete the command line that were added later. It would be last 3 lines of .profile file.

Comment: Habi, there's no need to get vulgar, his point is a legit one. Without more background on what you're up to, this sounds fishy to me as well. Please keep it cordial!

Comment: @slm leave that. Can you tell how to solve above problem?
I want to run command 

sudo startx<br/>

as soon as I login. I found that using that command gives me GUI temporarily. But, to open some file with GUI, I need to use gnome-open <file path>.

Comment: @Habi - thank you for tell us why! Does my answer satisfy what you need or do you need something more?

Comment: `sudo startx` is wrong. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jasonwryan I was tring to get GUI interface back. I can get GUI in guest account but not on primary account. I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Comment: That is not really any clearer. What does "get GUI interface back" mean? Have you broken something? Running X as root is a bad idea, and is unlikely to be a solution to whatever problem you actually have.

Comment: @jasonwryan Nothing's broken. My system is crash. Did you yourself have something broken? If "Running X as root is a bad idea", why don't you suggest me better idea. If possible, best idea.

Comment: Run it as your user: that is how it is designed to work...

Comment: @jasonwryan I would love to do that but, I have been facing problem regarding loging in as primary user. Previously, I was getting blackscreen with movable cursor only. But, now I can't even login into that account. After doing so many experiment trying to fix it, I've successfully created new problem. I'm sent back to login screen everytime I try to login. If you have any solution, you are warmly welcome.

Comment: A solution is only possible once you have identified and articulated your problem. Your question, as it stands, is an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're always interested in deleting the last 3 lines of a file you can simply do this using `head`.

```
$ head -n -# ex.txt
```

#### Example

Example file.

```
$ cat ex.txt 
1
2
3
4
5
```

Drop the last 3 lines:

```
$ head -n -3 ex.txt 
1
2
```

Do this and save it to the same file.

```
$ head -n -3 ex.txt | tee ex.txt 
1
2
```

Confirm update was applied to file `ex.txt`.

```
$ cat ex.txt 
1
2
```